# Error in unloadNamespace(package) : namespace ‘rlang’ is imported by ‘testthat’, ‘pkgload’,

Tags: r

I'd like to install the latest version of rlang from github, which is a later version than the one hosted on cran

This is my code

```
  remove.packages("rlang")
  install_github("r-lib/rlang")
  library("rlang")
```

It gives me this error

> Error in value[3L] :    Package ‘rlang’ version 0.4.0 cannot
> be unloaded:  Error in unloadNamespace(package) : namespace ‘rlang’ is
> imported by ‘testthat’, ‘pkgload’, ‘usethis’ so cannot be unloaded

Can I override this so that it does get unloaded?

Comment: Restart your session after removing package. Or remove it from command line R CMD REMOVE

Comment: I'd like to use that as part of a script. Can I include the CLI command in my script?

Comment: In a shell script yes

Comment: I see, but I can't include it in an R script. I'd have to have a .bash